# Pairing SCCM Boundary's and Boundary Groups in SCCM Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm attempting to get some boundary's I've created paired to their respective boundary groups. The boundary group description does contain the boundary group name and some added characters as an identifier (coa).

```
Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName *coa* | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -cotains *coa* -and $_.Value -match $Site.Name}
```

Or

```
$boundarys = Import-Csv C:\M\boundarydata.csv
ForEach ($line in $boundarys) { 

$boundary = Get-CMBoundary -BoundaryName $line.SiteName
Add-CMBoundaryToGroup $boundary
}
```

Not quite right. Where-Object doesn't return anything, surprisingly.

Comment: Use `-like` instead of `-contains` in the `where-object`

Comment: That's okay but still gets me no where near adding the boundarys to the groups

Comment: The reason why this code is not working is that you didn't gave the `Add-CMBoundaryToGroup` CMDLet the name of the boundarygroup to which the boundary should be added

Comment: @guiwhatsthat I appreciate your help but i answered it myself as per the below, please try to give a correct answer or be accurate and read the question properly before replying, otherwise it is of no use.

Comment: Your answer and your question doesn't match. In the question you tried with get and in the answer you create the boundary first.

Comment: That's correct, the answer contains the earlier used New-CMBoundary because it uses the pipeline to pipe the objects straight into their respective boundary groups without the need to reference them again using Get-CMBoundary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ForEach ($pos in $posrem) {
    New-CMBoundary -Name ($pos.StoreName + ' COA') `
    -Type IPRange -Value ($pos.COA + '-' + `
    $pos.COA2) | Add-CMBoundaryToGroup `
    -BoundaryGroupName ($pos.StoreName) 
}
```

This code creates boundarys from a CSV file, then add's them to pre existing boundary groups of the same name.

Took me a while to get that!!!  :)